# Windows docker image using nano server as base image is unable to launch bamboo remote agent on nano server

Tags: windows, docker, bamboo, nano-server

I have created a Windows docker image using nano server as the base image and installed dot net core SDK on it as nano server is a lightweight operating system. I have also downloaded and set the path for Java as it is required for Bamboo setup. The objective of this image is to start a nano server container which can launch a bamboo remote agent and build projects on this remote agent. 
The image which I have created is able to set java path and downloads the bamboo agent jar file. But on running the bamboo agent jar it says that the agent process is started but immediately the underlying agent gets terminated.

**The dockerfile looks like this-**

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver:10.0.14393.1770
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; 
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Install .NET Core SDK
ENV DOTNET_SDK_VERSION 2.0.2
ENV DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_URL https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-sdk-$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION-win-x64.zip
ENV DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_SHA 4864A36D3BE9D460A17D0EBE9D03B17CE224EC18880BCDBC087889F32DDFC2CF3753A1AB7D0414B1E73E863E0D10F5A8381E80EFFC7F7C0A50600DD82A1F0048
RUN Invoke-WebRequest $Env:DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_URL -OutFile dotnet.zip; `
if ((Get-FileHash dotnet.zip -Algorithm sha512).Hash -ne $Env:DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_SHA) { `
    Write-Host 'CHECKSUM VERIFICATION FAILED!'; `
    exit 1; `
}; `
`
Expand-Archive dotnet.zip -DestinationPath $Env:ProgramFiles\dotnet; `
Remove-Item -Force dotnet.zip

RUN setx /M PATH $($Env:PATH + ';' + $Env:ProgramFiles + '\dotnet' + ';' + $Env:ProgramFiles + '\jdk\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\bin')

# Trigger the population of the local package cache
ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE skip
RUN New-Item -Type Directory warmup; `
cd warmup; `
dotnet new; `
cd ..; `
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse warmup

RUN Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases/download/1.8.0.121-1/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64.zip -OutFile jdk.zip
RUN Expand-Archive jdk.zip -DestinationPath $Env:ProgramFiles\jdk
#RUN Move-Item $Env:Program Files\jdk\java* $Env:Program Files\jdk

RUN Invoke-WebRequest http://10.16.86.137:8085/agentServer/agentInstaller/atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-6.1.1.jar -OutFile bamboo-agent.jar


RUN echo 'java -jar C:\bamboo-agent.jar http://10.16.86.137:8085/agentServer/' >> C:\startup.ps1

CMD powershell ./startup.ps1
```

I tried the same using *nanoserver/java* as the base image and got the same result.

**The console logs look like this**

```
PS C:\> java -jar bamboo-agent.jar http://10.16.86.137:8085/agentServer/
Reinstalling wrapper binaries, reason: agent either not installed or outdated
Unzipping /classpath.zip to C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent home\classpath
Extracting 'MANIFEST.DAT'
Extracting 'atlassian-extras-decoder-api-3.3.0.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-cache-ehcache-2.11.3.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-annotations-1.1.0.jar'
Extracting 'truezip-kernel-7.6.jar'
Extracting 'activemq-client-5.14.5.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-core-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'svnkit-1.8.15.jar'
Extracting 'maven-model-3.0.5.jar'
Extracting 'commons-codec-1.8.jar'
Extracting 'commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar'
Extracting 'beehive-api-0.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'api-1.6.0-atlassian-8.jar'
Extracting 'geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-plugin-dotnet-6.1.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bandana-3.1.jar'
Extracting 'activemq-pool-5.14.5.jar'
Extracting 'maven-settings-builder-3.0.5.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-plugins-webresource-3.3.7.jar'
Extracting 'applinks-api-5.4.1.jar'
Extracting 'xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-plugins-spring-4.1.0.jar'
Extracting 'activemq-broker-5.14.5.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-plugins-webresource-api-3.3.7.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-agent-elastic-shared-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-agent-elastic-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-utils-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-localhost-1.1.0.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-secure-random-3.2.4.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-extras-common-3.3.0.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-cookie-tools-3.2.3.jar'
Extracting 'spring-messaging-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar'
Extracting 'jta-1.0.1B.jar'
Extracting 'maven-embedder-3.0.5.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-user-core-5.4.6.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-velocity-0.5.jar'
Extracting 'stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'bcprov-jdk15on-1.54.jar'
Extracting 'maven-repository-metadata-3.0.5.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-xwork-12-2.5.10-struts-2.jar'
Extracting 'plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar'
Extracting 'sal-spring-3.0.8.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-api-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-scheduler-quartz2-1.6.0.jar'
Extracting 'bamboo-specs-api-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-mail-2.7.19.jar'
Extracting 'spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-maven-embedder-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'ion-java-1.0.2.jar'
Extracting 'maven-settings-3.0.5.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-plugin-scripttask-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'maven-core-3.0.5.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-secure-xml-3.2.4.jar'
Extracting 'oro-2.0.8.jar'
Extracting 'applinks-host-5.4.1.jar'
Extracting 'commons-lang-2.6.jar'
Extracting 'bamboo-additional-config.jar'
Extracting 'maven-compat-3.0.5.jar'
Extracting 'javax.mail-1.5.2.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bucket-5.1.3.jar'
Extracting 'soy-template-renderer-plugin-api-4.0.4.jar'
Extracting 'freemarker-2.3.24-atlassian-2.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar'
Extracting 'jna-4.1.0.jar'
Extracting 'spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar'
 Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-plugin-triggercondition-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'jsch.agentproxy.pageant-0.0.7.jar'
Extracting 'jackson-annotations-2.7.9.jar'
Extracting 'jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar'
Extracting 'aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.164.jar'
Extracting 'spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar'
Extracting 'xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar'
Extracting 'spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar'
Extracting 'package-scanner-0.9.5.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-util-concurrent-4.0.0.jar'
Extracting 'quartz-2.2.3.jar'
Extracting 'aether-impl-1.13.1.jar'
Extracting 'jansi-1.11.jar'
Extracting 'security-classlist-api-0.3.21.jar'
Extracting 'platform-3.4.0.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-cache-api-2.11.3.jar'
Extracting 'commons-digester-1.8.jar'
Extracting 'sequence-library-1.0.3.jar'
Extracting 'javacvs-atlassian-20080407.jar'
Extracting 'aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-instrumentation-core-2.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-scheduler-core-1.6.0.jar'
Extracting 'commons-validator-1.5.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-plugins-osgi-events-4.1.0.jar'
Extracting 'jaxen-1.1.6.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-plugin-stashcommitviewer-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-agent-elastic-server-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-ip-3.1.jar'
Extracting 'slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-aws-1.0.149.jar'
Extracting 'jsch.agentproxy.core-0.0.7.jar'
Extracting 'staxmate-2.0.0.jar'
Extracting 'commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar'
Extracting 'activemq-jms-pool-5.14.5.jar'
Extracting 'aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.164.jar'
Extracting 'p4java-0.7.5-atlassian-13.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-johnson-1.0.jar'
Extracting 'mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-tenancy-api-2.0.0.jar'
Extracting 'aws-java-sdk-codedeploy-1.11.164.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-plugin-ant-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'bamboo-specs-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar'
Extracting 'minlog-1.3.0.jar'
Extracting 'ehcache-2.7.5.jar'
Extracting 'acegi-security-1.0.4.jar'
Extracting 'activeobjects-spi-1.2.3.jar'
Extracting 'jaxb-api-2.1.jar'
Extracting 'osuser-1.0-20060106.jar'
Extracting 'geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-2.0.0.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-extras-core-3.3.0.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-extras-legacy-3.3.0.jar'
Extracting 'jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.7.9.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-plugins-osgi-4.1.0.jar'
Extracting 'geronimo-transaction-3.1.jar'
Extracting 'jackson-core-2.7.9.jar'
Extracting 'maven-artifact-3.0.5.jar'
Extracting 'truezip-driver-zip-7.6.jar'
Extracting 'truezip-swing-7.6.jar'
Extracting 'joda-time-2.8.2.jar'
Extracting 'httpcore-4.4.6.jar'
Extracting 'sqljet-1.1.10.jar'
Extracting 'jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar'
Extracting 'applinks-spi-5.4.1.jar'
Extracting 'jackson-core-asl-1.9.1.jar'
Extracting 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-plugin-php-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'lucene-analyzers-common-4.6.0.jar'
Extracting 'ant-1.8.4.jar'
Extracting 'activemq-protobuf-1.1.jar'
Extracting 'aopalliance-1.0.jar'
Extracting 'hibernate-ehcache-5.2.10.Final.jar'
Extracting 'spring-context-support-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-plugins-webfragment-4.0.0.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-web-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'truezip-file-7.6.jar'
Extracting 'antlr-2.7.7.jar'
Extracting 'trilead-ssh2-1.0.0-build221.jar'
Extracting 'asm-5.0.3.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-deployments-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar'
Extracting 'commons-collections4-4.1.jar'
Extracting 'wagon-http-shared4-2.4.jar'
Extracting 'commons-httpclient-3.1-atlassian-2.jar'
Extracting 'lucene-core-4.6.0.jar'
Extracting 'geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.6_spec-1.0.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-extras-api-3.3.0.jar'
Extracting 'maven-plugin-api-3.0.5.jar'
Extracting 'aether-spi-1.13.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-plugins-api-4.1.0.jar'
Extracting 'fugue-2.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-plugins-webresource-common-4.1.0.jar'
Extracting 'webwork-compat-1.32.jar'
Extracting 'jxmpp-util-cache-0.4.2.jar'
Extracting 'maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-html-encoder-1.5.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-plugin-labeller-6.2.1.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-plugins-webfragment-api-4.0.0.jar'
Extracting 'hawtbuf-1.11.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-processutils-1.7.9.jar'
Extracting 'jul-to-slf4j-1.7.10.jar'
Extracting 'jdom-1.0.jar'
Extracting 'sourcemap-1.7.2.jar'
Extracting 'jsr305-1.1.jar'
Extracting 'commons-io-2.4.jar'
Extracting 'ant-launcher-1.8.4.jar'
Extracting 'objenesis-2.4.jar'
Extracting 'atlassian-bamboo-plugin-fisheyecommitviewer-6.2.1.jar'
Installing file: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\conf\wrapper.conf
Installing file: /generic/lib/wrapper.jar to: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\lib\wrapper.jar
Installing file: /generic/lib/bamboo-agent-bootstrap-jar-with-dependencies.jar to: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\lib\bamboo-agent-bootstrap.jar
Installing file: /generic/bin/BambooAgent.bat to:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\bin\BambooAgent.bat
Installing file: /generic/bin/InstallBambooAgent-NT.bat to: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\bin\InstallBambooAgent-NT.bat
Installing file: /generic/bin/StartBambooAgent-NT.bat to: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\bin\StartBambooAgent-NT.bat
Installing file: /generic/bin/StopBambooAgent-NT.bat to:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\bin\StopBambooAgent-NT.bat
Installing file: /generic/bin/UninstallBambooAgent-NT.bat to:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\bin\UninstallBambooAgent-NT.bat
Installing file: /arch/windows/64/wrapper.exe to:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\bin\wrapper.exe    
Installing file: /arch/windows/64/wrapper.dll to:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\lib\wrapper.dll
LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local
PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
USERDOMAIN: User Manager
ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
SystemDrive: C:
DOTNET_SDK_VERSION: 2.0.2
APPDATA: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming
BAMBOO_SERVER: http://10.16.86.137:8085/agentServer/
USERNAME: ContainerAdministrator
ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE: skip
Path:C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\
System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\
Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\jdk\
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\bin;
PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD
OS: Windows_NT
COMPUTERNAME: BB7F1D575456
BAMBOO_AGENT_HOME: "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home"
PROCESSOR_REVISION: 3c03
CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE: skip 
Path:C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\
System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\
Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program 
Files\jdk\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\bin;
PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD
OS: Windows_NT
COMPUTERNAME: BB7F1D575456
BAMBOO_AGENT_HOME: "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home"
PROCESSOR_REVISION: 3c03
CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
IGNORE_SERVER_CERT_NAME: false
SystemRoot: C:\Windows
TEMP: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
USERPROFILE: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator
TMP: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp
DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_URL:https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/
2.0.2/dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-win-x64.zip
CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
BAMBOO_SECURITY_TOKEN:
DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_SHA: 864A36D3BE9D460A17D0EBE9D03B17CE224EC18880BCDBC087889F32DDFC2CF3753A1AB7D0414B1E3E863E0D10F5A8381E80EFFC7F7C0A50600DD82A1F0048
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
windir: C:\Windows
Running [C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\bamboo-agent-home\bin\BambooAgent.bat]
Agent process started, shutdown hook registered, proceeding with log pump...
Waiting for the agent process to finish...
Underlying agent process has terminated cleanly,
Bamboo Agent Installer is shutting down, the underlying agent process has already been shut down.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The command `java -jar bamboo-agent.jar http://10.16.86.137:8085/agentServer/` is being executed in a RUN command, which will execute when you are building the image.

When you build an image, commands such as RUN execute and create a layer, and then terminate. This is what image building is, creating a bunch of FS layers that will be later used when running the container.
If you need to start the agent you need to have it started when running the container and that is done in a CMD command. A naive way to refactor you Dockerfile is to combine the last RUN and CMD as such:

```
CMD echo 'java -jar C:\bamboo-agent.jar http://10.16.86.137:8085/agentServer/' >> C:\startup.ps1 && powershell ./startup.ps1
```

Comment: I modified the Dockerfile with the combined CMD but I am still facing the same issue. I am facing this issue only with nano server. I tried the same dockerfile with windowsservercore and it launched the bamboo remote agent successfully.

Comment: Check the server-side logs for more info, the ones in Bamboo master.